# password authentication failed for user "postgres" (already edit 'pg_hba.conf' but didn't work)

Tags: postgresql

< Update for solution >

For future reference, there might be multiple versions of postgres in my computer since I install so many times while I was trying. So I didn't edit the exact 'pg_hba.conf' file. That cause the problem.

Eventually, I completely uninstall and reinstall the postgres by following this article:
https://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2021-01-28-how-to-completely-uninstall-homebrew-postgres/

It help me fixed the problem.

---

< Question >

I installed postgresql by brew on my mac,
but I keep having trouble to start using it and getting this message cause I don't know what's my password.

`psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

I had already edited my `pg_hba.conf`  file, modified it to

```
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all            127.0.0.1/32             trust
host    all             all            ::1/128                  trust
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all            127.0.0.1/32             trust
host    replication     all            ::1/128                  trust
```

p.s. I also tried set the 'method' to 'ident',add the 'address' with '127.0.0.1/32', and 'user' to 'postgres'. All these combination didn't work.

After that, I restart the server, but i still need password to connect to the server.

```
$postgres -V
postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.0
$brew services restart postgres
Stopping `postgresql`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
==> Successfully started `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
$psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres: 
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

And here are other things that I had tried in the past few days:

1. re-install postgresql by brew several times.
2. `psql -U postgres`
3. `$ sudo -u postgres psql -c "ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'postgres';"`

Please help me with this problem, I've stuck here for several days...

Comment: what happens if you go su - postgres and after that just type psql?

Comment: See your postgresql server logs, they should tell the exact line in `pg_hba.conf` that matches the connection attempt. Possibly you're editing a different `pg_hba.conf` than the one read by the server.

Comment: Did you `reload` the server after making the `pg_hba.conf` changes?